# Failed to resolve: com.github.worker8:RadioGroupPlus:v1.0.1

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-radiogroup

I am trying to build existing project in android studio 3.2.1 and I am using 
`com.github.worker8:RadioGroupPlus:v1.0.1` this dependency in the project though it was working in android studio 2.1 and now when I am building it in android studio 3.2.1 it throws
 `Failed to resolve: com.github.worker8:RadioGroupPlus:v1.0.1` this error. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: ok. thanks for the advice, will keep it in mind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [RadioGroupPlus](https://jitpack.io/p/worker8/radiogroupplus) Jitpack page.

**Step 1.** Add the JitPack repository to your build file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
```

**Step 2.** Add the dependency

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.github.worker8:radiogroupplus:v1.0.1'
}
```

The difference is using **radiogroupplus** instead of RadioGroupPlus.